# Get model Data from $parent model into in controller

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have the following code in form $parent.checkOut is working fine. But once i try to access this Data in conoller {this.$parent.checkOut} but it showing undefiend. Can you please help me how i can access these model Data into my controller

```
 <div class="input-group date">
                                        <input type="datetime" class="form-control" date-time
                                               ng-model="$parent.checkOut" view="date"
                                               min-view="date" format="YYYY-MM-DD" auto-close="true">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                    </div>
```

I just want to know $parent is support into angular-meteor or not.

Thanks.

Comment: You may not have provided enough information. Where is `$parent` coming from and why do you need it in this instance? If everything is okay, model should remain `$scope.checkOut` in controller.

Comment: i am using angular-datepicker for calender and you can't access there model without ng-model="$parent.checkOut" and in general to access this model in controller u can use  $scope.parent.checkout   But in angular-meteor it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you use ControllerAs syntax, so - try `$scope.$parent` and it should be defined